# Reflection in the line $y=mx+c$ via matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

I want to reflect the point $(a,b)$ in the line $y=mx+c$. The way I am thinking about it is that I need to  shift the line by $c$ in the negative y direction to then simply reflect in $y=mx$ via \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2} & \frac{-2m}{1+m^2} \\
\frac{2m}{1+m^2} & \frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2} 
\end{pmatrix}.In doing so I get the translated $(a',b')$ to be

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a' \\
b'
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
c
\end{pmatrix}
+ (\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2} & \frac{-2m}{1+m^2} \\
\frac{2m}{1+m^2} & \frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2} 
\end{pmatrix}(\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
c
\end{pmatrix}))
.$$

However, in trying to reflect $(0,8)$  through $y=−\frac{1}{2}x+2$ I get $(4.8,5.6)$ rather than the desired $(-4.8,-1.6)$. Can somebody assist me with this and explain to me why this is wrong and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

We get the reflection(image) $P'(x',y')$ of a point $P(x,y)$ in the line AB:$y=mx+c$  by demanding
PP'  to be perpendicular AB and the foot of perpendicular N such that $PN=P'N=PP'/2$:
$$\frac{x'-x}{m}=\frac{y'-y}{-1}=-2 \frac{mx-y+c}{1+m^2}$$
We get $$x'=-2\frac{m^2x-my+mc}{1+m^2}+x,~~ y'=2\frac{mx-y+c}{1+m^2}+y$$
$$\implies x'=\frac{(1-m^2)x+2my-2mc}{1+m^2}, ~~~y'=\frac{2mx+(m^2-1)y+2c}{1+m^2}$$
In the matrix notation:
$$\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{1+m^2}\begin{bmatrix} 1-m^2 & 2m &-2mc \\ 2m & m^2-1 & 2c \\ 0 & 0 & 1+m^2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
If $m=\tan \theta$ we can write
$$\begin{bmatrix}x' \\y' \\ 1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} \cos 2 \theta & \sin 2\theta & -c\sin 2\theta \\ \sin 2\theta & -\cos 2 \theta & 2c \cos^2 \theta \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
This can also be written as
$$\begin{bmatrix}x' \\y'\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} \cos 2 \theta & \sin 2\theta  \\ \sin 2\theta & -\cos 2 \theta  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} -c \sin 2 \theta \\ 2 c\cos^2 \theta \end{bmatrix}$$
The reflection of a point $P$ about $y=mx+c=\tan \theta~ x+c$ will be given by
$P'=T P+C,$ where
$$T=\begin{bmatrix} \cos 2 \theta & \sin 2\theta  \\ \sin 2\theta & -\cos 2 \theta  \end{bmatrix}$$

This $T$ matrix must not be confused with the rotation matrix $R$, where $P' =R P$ gives the coordinates $P'$ of the point $P$, when $P$ in the $x-y$ system is rotated by an angle $\theta$ anti-clockwise with respect to $x$-axis about the origin of a two dimensional cartesian coordinate system. Note that
$$R(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos  \theta & -\sin \theta  \\ \sin \theta & \cos  \theta  \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: +1, but you should establish the link with the solution of the OP by writing your last expression under the form: $\begin{bmatrix}x' \\  y'\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{1+m^2}\begin{bmatrix} 1-m^2 & 2m\\ 2m & m^2-1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\  y\end{bmatrix}+\frac{1}{1+m^2}\begin{bmatrix}-2mc \\  2c\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, thanks I have added some more stuff in the answer now.

Comment: See my (separed) second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix should be

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2} & \frac{2m}{1+m^2} \\
\frac{2m}{1+m^2} & \frac{-(1-m^2)}{1+m^2} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

(determinant $-1$).

What you have used is a rotation matrix (determinant $+1$).

The rest of your computation is correct.

**Recall:**  The linear isometries are characterized by **orthogonal** matrices with two characteristic forms:

1. Rotation:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b& \ \ \ a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\alpha)&-\sin(\alpha)\\ \sin(\alpha)&\ \ \cos(\alpha)\end{pmatrix}$$ (rotation with $\det=a^2+b^2=1$) where the geometrical meaning of $\alpha$ is (well known as) the rotation angle.

2. Symmetry:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a& \ \ \ b\\b&-a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(2\beta)& \ \ \sin(2\beta)\\ \sin(2\beta)&- \cos(2\beta)\end{pmatrix}$$ (with $\det=-(a^2+b^2)=-1$) where the geometric meaning of $\beta$ is (not well known as) the slope of the straight line with respect to which the symmetry is done. Not surprisingly :

$$\sin(2\beta)=2 \sin \beta \cos \beta=2 \tan \beta \cos^2 \beta=\dfrac{2m}{1+m^2} \ \text{where} \ m=\tan \beta$$

and a similar formula for $\cos(2 \beta)$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! A quick question, why is it a negative there?

Comment: @Maths It's difficult to answer "why" meaningfully since we don't know how you got your matrix in the first place. It might be helpful for you to note, though, that your matrix has the wrong sign for *both* of the entries in the second column.

Comment: There are 2 answers to your "why" question:1)  the computation  gives $ad-bc=\dfrac{[-(1-m^2)^2-4m^2)}{(1+m^2)^2}=\dfrac{(-1-2m^2-m^4)}{(1+m^2)^2}=-1$; 2) Linear isometries are characterized by **orthogonal** matrices with two characteristic forms $\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$ (rotations with $\det=a^2+b^2=1$) and $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{pmatrix}$ (symmetries with $\det=-(a^2+b^2)=-1$).

Comment: I have added some more more information in my answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification. I still have a few questions if you don't mind. I understand that we are basically rotating by twice the angle that is made with the horizontal but shouldn't it be twice the angle between the point and the line? Moreover, under the interpretation that the determinant is a scaling factor why is it negative?

Comment: 1) It is normal that the "final matrix" is independant from the angle of $(x,y)$ with the straight line, but depends only on parameter $m$. 2) Dealing with the determinant,  the determinant is the coefficient by which you multiply an area to get the area of the image (for example, using an enlargment by a factor 2, with matrix diag(2,2), therefore determinant $4=, an area will be multiplied by 4. But the important thing is that we must think in terms of **oriented areas**; for example, if A(1,0) and B(0,1), the area of triangle OAB is 1/2. Considering symmetry with respect to Oy, its image...

Comment: ... is $OA'B'$ but saying this, you turn $O \rightarrow A' \rightarrow B'$ in the **indirect orientation (clockwise instead of anticlockwise for initial triangle OAB)**. Therefore you have to consider that area$(OA'B')=-1/2$ (negative), which is in coincidence with the fact that the determinant of matrix $S_{Oy}=\binom{-1 \ \ 0}{\ \ 0 \ \ 1}$ is $-1$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way to obtain your transformation.

Let $L$ be the line with equation $y=mx+c$. Let $P(x,y)$ be a generic point and $P'(x',y')$ its image by orthogonal symmetry with respect to line $L$.

This orthogonal symmetry can be characterized by two properties:

- Symmetry: midpoint of [PP'], $\left(\dfrac{x'+x}{2},\dfrac{y'+y}{2}\right)$ belongs to line $L$.
- orthogonality: $\vec{PP'}=\binom{x'-x}{y'-y} \perp \binom{1}{m}$ (directing vector of $L$).

These two conditions can be transformed into:

$$\dfrac{y'+y}{2}=m\dfrac{x'+x}{2}+c \ \iff \ mx'-y'=-mx+y-2c\tag{1}$$

$$1(x'-x)+m(y'-y)=0 \ \iff \ x'+my'=x+my\tag{2}$$

Grouping (1) and (2):

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}m&-1\\1&m \end{pmatrix}}_M \begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-m&1\\1&m \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-2c\\0\end{pmatrix}\tag{3}$$

Multiplying LHS and RHS of (3) by $M^{-1}=\tfrac{1}{1+m^2}\begin{pmatrix}m&1\\-1&m \end{pmatrix}$ gives:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\tfrac{1}{1+m^2}\begin{pmatrix}m&1\\-1&m \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-m&1\\1&m \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+\tfrac{2c}{1+m^2}\begin{pmatrix}-m\\1\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$